# Functional Equation similar to Cauchy's: $\{f(x)\}+\{f(y)\}=\{f(x+y)\}$

Tags: functional-equations

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$ such that for any $x,y\in{}\mathbb{Q}$ we have
> $$\{f(x)\}+\{f(y)\}=\{f(x+y)\}\text.$$

Note that $\{t\}$ denotes the fractional part of $t$ for instance $\{1.5\}=0.5$

**Progress:** Since $t-\lfloor t\rfloor=\{t\}$, I found out that

\begin{align*}
f(x)+f(y)-\lfloor f(x)\rfloor-\lfloor f(y)\rfloor &= f(x+y)-\lfloor f(x+y) \rfloor. \\
f(x)+f(y)-f(x+y)&=\lfloor f(x)\rfloor +\lfloor f(y) \rfloor -\lfloor f(x+y) \rfloor.
\end{align*}

So one trivial solution is $f(x)=c$ where $c$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Put $g(x)=\{f(x)\} \in [0,1[$. Then you have $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$ for all $x,y$. Show that for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, we have $g(nx)=ng(x)$.

Comment: I managed to show that $g(nx)=ng(x)$ via induction so $\{f(nx)\}=n\{f(x)\}$. So does this mean that the only group of solutions is $f(x)=c$ where $c\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If $\{f(x)\}$ is not $0$, for $n$ large, you have $n\{f(x)\}>1$. But this is $\{f(nx)\}\in [0,1[$

Comment: Just for clarity : the notation means all numbers between 0 and 1, including 0 and excluding 1, right? Someone seemed a bit not sure about it.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have understood.

Comment: @JackFrost No, but any map $\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Z$ will do